# How can I set listener for clientwebsocket in c#?

Tags: c#, clientwebsocket

```
ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket();
socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(socketURL), CancellationToken.None);
```

I have created ClientWebSocket using given code above in c#.
Now I want to listen to the data received through this socket.
How can I set listener for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `await Task.WhenAll(Receive(socket ), Send(socket ));`  and define the followings:

```
static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocket);
static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket);
```

Example from [github:paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples](https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples/blob/master/HttpListenerWebSocketEcho/Client/Client.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    class Client
    {
        private static object consoleLock = new object();
        private const int sendChunkSize = 256;
        private const int receiveChunkSize = 64;
        private const bool verbose = true;
        private static readonly TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Connect("ws://localhost/wsDemo").Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

            try
            {
                webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket), Send(webSocket));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webSocket != null)
                    webSocket.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine();

                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sendChunkSize];

            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                random.NextBytes(buffer);

                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);
                LogStatus(false, buffer, buffer.Length);
   
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveChunkSize];
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {                
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    LogStatus(true, buffer, result.Count);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void LogStatus(bool receiving, byte[] buffer, int length)
        {
            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = receiving ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} bytes... ", receiving ? "Received" : "Sent", length);

                if (verbose)
                    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, length));

                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you please help me how can I detect event when socket is closed/opened?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48406896/14048240